# Redirects do not work in my functions defined in Laravel AppServiceProvider.php

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

Redirects do not work in my functions defined in Laravel AppServiceProvider.php

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function register()
{
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../Functions/functions.php';
}
```

**functions.php**

```
 function test(){

        if($x == $y){
        return redirect()->route('products')->with(['type' => 'error', 'message' => 'Oops.']);
        }else{
         //!I don't want the code to do anything and I want it to go back to the controller and continue running.
        }
```

Comment: why do you need to redirect from function? instead of a controller.

Comment: Because I use it inside many controllers and a constant function can be called from anywhere. @BhargavChudasama

Comment: so what are you getting?

Comment: What error you are getting ? Have you defined 'products' in your routing ? Check php artisan route:list and see 'products' exists there ?

Comment: There is no problem in this regard, the controls go to the products. It doesn't return an error. continues processing directly. But I'm pretty sure it goes into the function, I checked that. @AqibJaved

Answer (score 1):

Use `test()` function with `return` so it will be redirected to your defined route.

Write down this way when you call your `test()` for redirect

```
return test();
```

**Updated Code in Function**

check the condition as based on condition return `route or false`

```
function test(){
    if($x == $y){
        return redirect()->route('products')->with(['type' => 'error', 'message' => 'Oops.']);
    }else{
        //!I don't want the code to do anything and I want it to go back to the controller and continue running.
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Update Code when You call Function**

```
if(test()){
   return test();
}
```

Comment: Yes this worked but this time the code flow stops and I can't resume. I'm editing the question a bit more now

Comment: @kkkgg update my code please check as per your new updated question

Comment: Which means you‘re executing `test()` twice in your example, that‘s not very clever ..

Comment: @dbf What is your solution?

Comment: Well, `test()` has many responsibilities here, but if you ignore that, it‘s simply saving the value and return, if that is what test should do, like `if( ($test = test()) ) return $test;`.

Comment: It's better you should post this as an answer :) @dbf

Comment: Just add it to yours, it’s not worth an answer if it doesn’t differ technically